# Disable IntelliJ Starred (Package) Imports?

Tags: java, autocomplete, intellij-idea

I'm a migrating Eclipse IDE user and am learning my way round IntelliJ IDEA 9.

By default Eclipse IDE won't use a starred import until you import 99 classes from the same package, so it practically never happens.

But IntelliJ IDEA seems only too keen to do it, and I can't work out how to disable it.

For example, after typing `JList` then <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to auto-import, the whole `javax.swing` package is imported instead of just the class I specify.

I tried excluding `javax.swing` from the auto-completion, but that just stops *any* Swing classes from being suggested, which is counter-productive.

Comment: IntelliJ 9?  Version 16 is on the way. Upgrade to the community edition or buy a license.

Answer (score 374, accepted):

You can set this setting here.

In **IDEA 14**+ the sequence is:

`Settings` > `Editor` > `Code Style` > `Java` > `Imports` > `Class count to use import with '*'`

In older version of IDEA:

`Settings` -> `Java` -> `Code Style` -> `Imports` -> `Class count to use import with '*'`

The feature can not be disabled. You need to set it to a high value, e.g. 99.

In 2016.1.1 version
You should also remove the lines under `Packages to Use Import with '*'`, 
e.g. `import javax.*;`

Comment: Now both `Class count to use import with '*'` and `Names count to use static import with '*'` are set to `99` to copy Eclipse's behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work if you set this value to 0, rather than setting to a high number

Comment: Threshold needs to be high for me. If I set that threshold to 0, the feature remains enabled. Worst, I end-up with stars imports everywhere (IDEA 2017.1).

Comment: 0 destroyed me, reverted and set it to 1000

Comment: This is language specific, so remember to set this under Kotlin if you're using that or a mixed project.

Comment: In verison 2022.2, you can leave the box empty instead of 99.

Answer (score 69):

**IntelliJ IDEA:**

- **14** & **15** & **16 EAP**

  `File > Settings... > Editor > Code Style > Java > Imports` > in `General` area add a big number for `Class count to use import with '*':` / `Names count to use static import with '*':`

  [image: File > Settings... > Editor > Code Style > Java > Imports > General > Class count to use import with '*']

**IntelliJ IDEA:**

- **12** & **13**

  `File > Settings... > Code Style > Java > Imports` > in `General` area add a big number for `Class count to use import with '*':`
  [image: File > Settings... > Code Style > Java > Imports > General > Class count to use import with '*']

  P.S.: `Java` is after `Code Style` in the path.

Comment: Is there really no way to tell Intellij 15 never to use starred imports?  I mean without specifying a class count??!

Comment: That's what I suspected - but seems odd!

Comment: This is nutty. I _like_ starred imports. What's the downside again? Really. (Not in some hypothetical situation where there are overlapping names.)

Comment: @MarkHu When someone views your code outside the scope of an IDE (e.g. on Github), it becomes really difficult to figure out which package a class is coming from.

Answer (score 4):

And you also have to remove package names from the "Packages to use import with *" list box just below the "Class count to use import with *" text boxes. Swing and AWT are there by default I think. I still was having import javax.swing.*; added even though I had the class count set to 999. I used the minus sign button to remove Swing and Awt from the box and then it worked.